# Usando 'hide' e 'show' em uma div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Eu tenho uma div que quando eu clico nela ela mostra e esconde uma ul.
Com o código assim:

```
<ul class="homeMenuItens">
        <li>
            <div pagina='/produtos/incendio' class="homeMenuPai">Incendio</div>
            <ul id="incendio" class="homeMenuFilhos" style="display:none">
                <li  pagina='paginaSYS' onclick='window.location=\"/paginaSYS\"'>tituloMenuSYS</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

O Jquery está assim:

```
$(".homeMenuPai").click(function() {
    $(".homeMenuFilhos").css('display','none');
    if($(this).parent().find(".homeMenuFilhos").css('display') == 'none'){
        $(this).parent().find(".homeMenuFilhos").show();
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().find(".homeMenuFilhos").hide();
    }    

});
```

Está funcionando, assim que clico no  Menu titulo, por exemplo, ele mostra os itens abaixo.
O Problema é que se eu clicar na Div mais de uma vez, ele não esconde os itens. Ele só esconde quando eu clico nas outras divs.

A estrutura é assim
div TITULO
ul UL COM ITENS
li LISTAGEM de ITENS

Tenho 4 divs iguais

Na imagem abaixo mostra os 4 Menus principais, se eu clicar no 2, o 1 fecha, mas se eu clicar no 1 de novo para fechar, ele não fecha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria interessante criar um **http://jsfidle.net** para mostrar exatamente o que está acontecendo, assim vai ficar mais fácil de ajuda-lo

Comment: Oi @ErlonCharles vai ficar complicado colocar no jsfidle pois o código está cheio de palavras reservadas, coloquei uma imagem para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Apenas para entender você quer algo qui funcione como isso?http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Comment: @ErlonCharles, o Vieira me ajudou da forma que eu precisava, valeu. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você esta setando todos os elementos `.homeMenuFilhos` com `display = none` e depois verificando se é `display == none`, ou seja, o `if` sempre vai ser verdadeiro. Remova alinha:

```
$(".homeMenuPai").click(function() {
    //remova esta linha --> $(".homeMenuFilhos").css('display','none');
    if($(this).parent().find(".homeMenuFilhos").css('display') == 'none'){
        $(this).parent().find(".homeMenuFilhos").show();
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().find(".homeMenuFilhos").hide();
    }    

});
```

Ou se quiser ocultar todos os outros e exibir somente o atual faça assim:

```
$(".homeMenuPai").click(function() {

   if($(this).parent().find(".homeMenuFilhos").css('display') == 'none'){
        $(".homeMenuFilhos").css('display','none');
        $(this).parent().find(".homeMenuFilhos").show();
   }
   else{
        $(this).parent().find(".homeMenuFilhos").hide();
   }    

});
```

Comment: Oi @Vieira, show de bola sua dica. O problema, é que quando eu clico em 2 eu quero esconder um deles e não deixar dois mostrando, entende?

Comment: Veja a edição que fiz

Comment: Opa, nota 10 cara, era exatamente isso que eu queria! Abraço

Comment: Blz, se funcionou não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita.

Comment: Com certeza, não marquei na hora, pois tive que esperar alguns minutos. :D

Comment: Para evitar mexer com o `display` dos elementos, eu costumo criar uma classe CSS simples, depois de todas as outras declarações: `.HID { display:none; }`. Assim, para esconder eu acrescento a classe `HID` ao elemento, e para mostrar, apenas removo a classe `HID` dele.